# SQL Server Management Studio Data Tables to R

Tags: r, sql-server, database, dataframe, merge

After connecting to SQL Server Management Studio through R I have extracted 5 data tables I need. An example of my code for extracting one of the tables into R is:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblBenchmarkindex" BenchmarkIndex1 <- sqlQuery(db, sql)`
```

I do this exact code for four other tables. I need to merge multiple tables together to get one big "aggregate table", and since each table is linked by one or more columns I figure merging is my best bet. The problem I am having now is this:

Table 2 has 4 variables and roughly a little over 808,000 observations: Factor, Exposure, DataDate, BsID

Table 3 has 3 variables and roughly 8000 observations: Factor, Risk, DataDate

What I've tried for example is:

```
df<-merge(x=Table2,y=Table3,by="Factor",all.x=TRUE)
```

The output I get doesn't include table3's Datadate, which I assume is because I did a left outer join, but I need that included without added duplicate observations. When I do a natural join or a right outer join I get an obsered amount of "added" observations.

My concise question is: how do I merge these two datatables by the variable they have in common (Factor) while not creating any added variables? I am very new to R, but feel I understand the different types of join functions, but feel I am not implementing them correctly.

Comment: How carefully did you look at the results? Because my expectation would be (based on the documentation for `merge`) that the result would have columns `DataDate.x` and `DataDate.y` coming from Table2 and Table3 respectively.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you focus on your sql statement instead to join the tables within the database itself (it's what they're designed for).  Likely (hopefully) your database has indexes on your tables that will speed your joins; whereas importing them into R first will loose any relationship and index information.  Moreover, inner joins may result in deprecated datasets where keys don't exist or conditions don't match, so you end up importing less data into R, which might gain some efficiency if there's a lot of data to download.

Comment: Your merge() call looks correct and it should bring-in all columns, as you expect.  Can you do "dput(head(Table2))" and "dput(head(Table3))" and copy-paste that output into your question to show the specific data that you're working with?  Will help others to see what's going on and test solutions.

Comment: Soren, with the help of your advice, I decided to join the tables in the database and you're right that made it a lot easier and more efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it selects only the specific data.frame columns you're interested in to pass in to the merge function and should yield a merged data.frame result with Factor, Exposure and Risk only (without DataDate) as the question asks:

```
df<-merge(x=Table2[,c("Factor","Exposure")],y=Table3[,c("Factor","Risk")],by="Factor",all.x=TRUE)
```